# Error while building openssl for windows ce 6.0

Tags: openssl, windows-ce

on running command "nmake -f ms\cedll.mak" from visual studio 2005 command prompt got the following error.

```
cl /Fotmp32dll_x86\b_sock.obj  -Iinc32 -Itmp32dll_x86 /MC /O1i /W3 /GF /
Gy /nologo -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DOPENSSL_SYSNAME_WINCE -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -D
L_ENDIAN -DDSO_WIN32 -DNO_CHMOD -DOPENSSL_SMALL_FOOTPRINT -D_WIN32_WCE=600 -DUND
ER_CE=600 -DWCE_PLATFORM_VC-CE -Dx86 -D_ -ID:/wcecompat/include -DOPENSSL_NO_RC5
 -DOPENSSL_NO_MD2 -DOPENSSL_NO_KRB5 -DOPENSSL_NO_JPAKE -DOPENSSL_NO_STATIC_ENGIN
E /Zi /Fdtmp32dll_x86/lib -D_WINDLL -D_DLL  -DOPENSSL_BUILD_SHLIBCRYPTO -c .\cry
pto\bio\b_sock.c
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/MC'
b_sock.c
D:\Program Files\Windows CE Tools\wce600\DO_X86_600\include\x86\winsock.h(764) :
 warning C4005: 'ENAMETOOLONG' : macro redefinition
        D:\wcecompat\include\errno.h(128) : see previous definition of 'ENAMETOO
LONG'
D:\Program Files\Windows CE Tools\wce600\DO_X86_600\include\x86\winsock.h(767) :
 warning C4005: 'ENOTEMPTY' : macro redefinition
        D:\wcecompat\include\errno.h(137) : see previous definition of 'ENOTEMPT
Y'
.\crypto\bio\b_sock.c(195) : warning C4013: 'getservbyname' undefined; assuming
extern returning int
.\crypto\bio\b_sock.c(195) : warning C4047: '=' : 'servent *' differs in levels
of indirection from 'int'
.\crypto\bio\b_sock.c(629) : error C2079: 'sa_in6' uses undefined struct 'sockad
dr_in6'
.\crypto\bio\b_sock.c(776) : error C2224: left of '.sin6_addr' must have struct/
union type
.\crypto\bio\b_sock.c(776) : error C2224: left of '.sin6_addr' must have struct/
union type
.\crypto\bio\b_sock.c(776) : error C2168: 'memset' : too few actual parameters f
or intrinsic function
.\crypto\bio\b_sock.c(777) : error C2224: left of '.sin6_addr' must have struct/
union type
.\crypto\bio\b_sock.c(861) : error C2079: 'sa_in6' uses undefined struct 'sockad
dr_in6'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"D:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/bin\c
l.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Comment: It seems that you have not run Config.

Comment: I tried the following sequence 
1. perl Configure VC-CE
2. call .\ms\do_ms.bat
3. nmake -f .\ms\cedll.mak

Comment: Try "/D _WIN32_WCE=0x600", I believe that this is the way that version 6.0 is expected to be defined.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

"#    if !defined(OPENSSL_NO_SOCK) && defined(_WIN32_WINNT)" with

"#    if !defined(OPENSSL_NO_SOCK) && ( defined(_WIN32_WINNT) ||     defined(_WIN32_WCE))" in "openssl-1.0.1e\e_os.h" @ line 273

For more info - http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/Windows-CE-VC-CE-Compilation-problem-td45909.html